# Maximization of multivariable function $ M = \frac{a+1}{a^{2}+ 2a+2} + \frac{b+1}{b^{2}+ 2b+2} + \frac{c+1}{c^{2}+ 2c+2}$ subject to constraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, substitution, sum-of-squares-method

This is purely out of curiosity. I have this set of a high school entrance Math exam in Vietnam (a special high school for gifted kids, the exam was held 3 days ago, maybe 4, taking into account the time zone). Here's one question that I've been stuck with:

With $a, b, c$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $ab + bc + ca + abc =2$, find the max of

$ M = \frac{a+1}{a^{2}+ 2a+2} + \frac{b+1}{b^{2}+ 2b+2} + \frac{c+1}{c^{2}+ 2c+2}$

I'm just curious what kind(s) of techniques these junior high students can use, since as far as I remember when I was at that age, calculus and derivatives aren't taught until high school.

Comment: If this problem set is online, do you mind sharing the link?

Comment: @Ovi if you are interested, I can translate and type them down, because they are in Vietnamese.

Comment: here is the [full exam questions](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Aj4ZGARB1YpinJVBOOB89hIVF0lq7Q). Excuse me for the translation, my vocab in geometry is very limited...

Comment: Thanks a lot I would appreciate that very much, but please if it is a lot of work for you don't do it.

Comment: Oh I see you already posted.Thank you again very much!

Comment: @Ovi I made a mistake in Q2.1, p and q must be prime numbers. I corrected the file.

Comment: @userrandom In the problem $Q1-2$ there is a typo. $\sqrt{1(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}.$ What is it?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg it should be 2! I fixed it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a=b=c=\sqrt3-1$ then we get a value $\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, let $x=\frac{a+1}{\sqrt3}$, $y=\frac{b+1}{\sqrt3}$ and $z=\frac{c+1}{\sqrt3}$.

Hence, the condition gives $x+y+z=3xyz$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3x^2+1}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3x^2+\frac{3xyz}{x+y+z}}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y+z}{3(x+y)(x+z)}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$ or
$$9(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq8(x+y+z)^2$$ and since
$$9(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq8(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$$ it's just 
$$\sum_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that
$$xy+xz+yz\geq x+y+z$$ or
$$xy+xz+yz\geq(x+y+z)\sqrt{\frac{3xyz}{x+y+z}}$$ or
$$(xy+xz+yz)^2\geq3xyz(x+y+z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: @userrandom Do you mean $9(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\geq8(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)$?  if so it's $9(x^2y+x^2z+y^2x+y^2z+z^2x+z^2y+2xyz)\geq8(x^2y+x^2z+y^2x+y^2z+z^2x+z^2y+3xyz)$ or $x^2y+x^2z+y^2x+y^2z+z^2x+z^2y\geq6xyz,$ which is AM-GM if you wish. Also see my previous post.

Comment: yes, that part, I typed wrong in the comment again... (no 9), since I thought you were rewriting $\sum_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2\geq0.$ (didnt see that it's just z).

Comment: @userrandom No. It's fourth degree. It must be $\sum\limits_{cyc}z^2(x-y)^2\geq0$.

Comment: the fourth cyc sum...

Comment: @userrandom Do you ask from here come $\sum\limits_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0$? If so, we need to prove that $x^2y+x^2z+y^2x+y^2z+z^2x+z^2y-6xyz\geq0$ or $x^2z-2xyz+y^2z+y^2x-2xyz+z^2x+z^2y-2xyz+x^2y\geq0$ or $z(x-x)^2+x(y-z)^2+y(z-x)^2\geq0$ or $\sum\limits_{cyc}z(x-y)^2\geq0$.

Comment: Haha, we keep misunderstanding each other (and I kept mistyping things). yes, that's the part, and no because I understood it, it's just the first time I didn't see the cyc sum (since I read from the bottom up I thought it's the same as the fifth cyc sum), but then I got it and expanded it and all looks nice. But really thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 6):

The functional form of $M$ suggests us to change variable to $u = a+1, v = b+1, w = c + 1$.
In terms of them, the expression of $M$ simplifies to

$$M = \frac{u}{1+u^2} + \frac{v}{1+v^2} + \frac{w}{1+w^2}$$

The constraint $abc + ab + bc + ca = 2$ can be rewritten as

$$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1) - (a+b+c) - 1 = 2\quad\iff\quad u + v + w - uvw = 0$$

Since $a,b,c > 0$, $u,v,w \in (1,\infty)$. Pick $A, B, C \in (\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $u = \tan A$,$v = \tan B$ and $w = \tan C$.
The constraint tell us
$$\tan(A+B+C) = \frac{u+v+w - uvw}{1 - uv - vw - wu} = 0
\quad\implies\quad A+B+C = k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Since $A + B + C \in (\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{2})$, $k$ equals to $1$
and  $A + B + C = \pi$.

In terms of $A,B,C$, the expression we want to maximize becomes

$$M = \frac{\tan A}{1+\tan^2 A} + \frac{\tan B}{1+\tan^2 B} + \frac{\tan C}{1+\tan^2 C} = \frac12 \left[ \sin(2A) + \sin(2B) + \sin(2C) \right]$$

This is nothing but the area of triangle inscribed inside unit circle with
angles $2A$, $2B$ and $2C$ subtended at center. It is well known for such triangles, the one which maximize the area is an equilateral triangle. This implies $M$ is maximized when

$$A = B = C = \frac{\pi}{3} \implies a = b = c = \tan\frac{\pi}{3} - 1 = \sqrt{3} - 1$$

and the maximum value of $M$ is $\displaystyle\;\frac{3}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{3} = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$.

Comment: Very nice (+1). If you don't mind the question, how did you become so proficient at these this type of questions? It's a bit embarrasing that as a math undergrad, I am unable to solve these questions. Do you have any reccomendations for sources where I could learn this?

Comment: I like how you approach this without (possibly) having to to guess the answer first. This is very cool, and still doesn't use too complex tools (but for junior high I'm not certain they taught it or not). Still, thanks.

Comment: @Ovi I'm just lucky this time. Instead of trying to solve them, just treat them as little puzzle. If you can do them, great, If not, find another puzzle.

Comment: @userrandom The first step, changing variable to $u,v,w$, is sort of obvious. The key is I find the expression $u + v + w - uvw = 0$ looks familiar. It looks like the numerator of triple angle formula for tan which should have been taught in high schools (at least in Asia). It makes me wonder whether the inequality is geometric in origin...

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score -1):

Here Laplace multipliers, derivatives and gradients do not exist. Only multiplying and checking if something simplifies.

In this case, symmetry for simplifying the problem into:
$$
\mathcal{M}: 3{x+1 \over x^2+2x+2}\\
st. x^3+3x^2=2
$$

This holds because every term on the function is a sum of independent terms. In here symmetry is not a false friend.

Which reduces to finding the positive roots of $x^3+3x^2-2=0$. We do not know to solve a cubic equation, so we only can guess to break the polynomial. Our first guess is $x=-1$. Broken:
$$
(x^3+x^2+2x^2+2x-2x-2)/(x+1)=x^2+2x-2 
$$

And the others two are given by, yes, we know how to solve that already:
$$
x=\frac 12 (-2\pm\sqrt{4+8})=-1\pm \sqrt{3}
$$

Hence the only positive solution is $x=\sqrt{3}-1=a=b=c$ and $M=3{\sqrt{3}\over 3+1-2\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{3}-2+2}=3{\sqrt{3}\over 4}\sim 1.3$.

What if they are not equal?. Suppose $a=b=1,c=x$:
$$
\mathcal{M}: \frac45+{x+1 \over x^2+2x+2}\\
st. 3x=2
$$
then$x=2/3$ and $M=\frac45+{2/3+1 \over 4/9+4/3+2}=\frac45+{15 \over 34}\sim 1.2<1.3$

Yes, symmetry here helps, and the solution is a maximum.

Comment: `symmetry for simplifying the problem` How do you argue that symmetry doesn't give you a minimum, instead of a maximum, or just some local extremum as opposed to a global one.

Comment: I like your intuition !

Comment: Comment removed. The gradient still points to zero everywhere, and this is still an hyperbola-shaped domain. And again, this not on the sight of a school boy

Comment: Lagrange multipliers? chao.